# Access-Control-Allow-Origin contains invalid value

Tags: sails.js

when i send a request in angular 2 using http service ,the browser showing following error.
can any one tell the solution ???

> XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://192.168.1.59:1340/User/add. Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: The 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header contains the invalid value ''. Origin 'http://192.168.1.59:8083' is therefore not allowed access.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to enable `cors` in the `config/cors.js` file

```
allRoutes: false, // Change to true if you want to enable cors in all routes.


origin: 'https://myapp.com,https://auth.myapp.com' // use * for any origin.
```

If you want to enable cors only for a particular route, in `config/routes.js`

```
'get /foo/bar': {
    controller: 'FooController',
    action: 'bar',
    cors: true
  },
```

Answer (score 0):

You nead the server to enable CORS (cross origin resource sharing)

Ref: http://sailsjs.org/documentation/concepts/security/cors

simply enable allRoutes in **config/cors.js**:  allRoutes: true